# Замена картинок на html странице в цикле

Tags: jquery, html

В общем у меня есть страничка html и несколько картинок на ней с уникальными "id".
Я пытаюсь в js в цикле от k = 0 до k < кол-во картинок поменять им src по id. Вот как это выглядит. k выше задана.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        k = k.toString();
        cur = files[k].toString();
        $("#"+k).attr("src", "images/gallery/"+cur);
        k++;
    }
```

files - массив, элементы которого представляют собой string вида 5.jpg
В общем-то не заменяет картинки, потестил, вроде как виновата ("#"+k), но это же string, должно же работать

Comment: Фиг в том, что в отдельном файле js я таким же способом делал, но без цикла. Все работает

Comment: Сбросьте весь код на jsfiddle или на схожий ресурс. Тут не ясно что в переменных k и files хранится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не пробежаться по картинкам циклом each?

```
$.each($('.someContainer img'), function(element, index){
    var url = 'images/gallery/' + files[index];
    $(element).attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Отличный вариант. С помощью него переделал другие не очень то "красивые" элементы кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

1. переменная k не определена. думаю должно быть так: `k = i.toString();`
2. относительные адреса `"images/gallery/"+cur` попробуй заменить на абсолютные `"/images/gallery/"+cur`   : http://take.ms/tCnnR

Comment: > k выше задана.

Если k это число, то в чем сакральный смысл k.toString()? Или там id-ишники типа "1", "2", "3" и т.д? Без html кода и всего скрипта, имхо, тут можно только гадать.